# Is it possible to create an Azure worker role in any C++?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

As in the title: Is it possible to create the worker role (WR) in Azure in any .Net language? In Visual Studio, only C# and VB have the templates to do the worker roles. All examples I saw show only this way (+ P/Invoke of C++ code). However, I do not understand why it cannot be done in .Net C++? Can I ask for a small explanation or an example how to create C++ WR?

Comment: Why would you want to use C++/CLI for something like this instead of C# or VB.NET? What would be the advantage?

Comment: I have a code in C++. I would prefer not to mix the languages only because I need to start something. The easiest way would be to port C++ to C++/CLI and add OnStart/Run to such modified code so it would be the working role. In Run, it just calls what was in main() before. It was my idea. However, I do not know it is possible as I couldn't find any examples/info about it.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted (I corrected this mistake)?  It's a perfectly legit question, and it's perfectly consistent with the FAQ guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The Role startup code in OnStart() will be CLR code (C# or VB.NET), which can easily launch exe's written in anything - C, C++, Java, whatever. Same thing with startup tasks, which run a command script that can install software (via MSI, unzipping files, etc), run exes, launch servers... whatever you want to do.

The .NET code you need to deal with is the "scaffolding" code - the code that sets up the environment, launches processes, redirects stdout/stderr, configures diagnostics, etc.

Comment: OK, so can it be done in C++/CLI? If yes - how; if not - why.